# How to hide select list if it is empty

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Following code works fine but i want to hide `.search-form #city` if it doesnt have selected attribute or if it is empty. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
$('.search-form #city').parent().hide()
cities = $('.search-form #city').html()
$('.search-form #country').change ->
  country = $('.search-form #country :selected').text()
  escaped_country = country.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
  options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_country}']").html()
  if options
    $('.search-form #city').html(options)
    $('.search-form #city').parent().show()
  else
    $('.search-form #city').empty()
    $('.search-form #city').parent().hide()
```

Comment: So I guess this isn't your code, from all the filters used here that should be the least of trouble. Using `.search-form` class in `.search-form #city` is ambiguous, `#city` should be unique, therefor it's an `ID`. Start with the attribute as in `typeof $('#city').attr('selected') !== 'undefined'` and if the list is empty `$('#city').children('li').length === 0)` ..

Comment: you are right this isnt my code. actual hierarchy is following  `$('.search-form .field #city').parent().hide()` and i want to hide `.field` if #city doesnt selected.

Comment: Well the code to do this is just 2 comments above this one, just replace `$('#city')` with `$('.search-form .field #city')` and be done with it. That still means that you have no clue that `#city` needs to be UNIQUE. It should only appear once in the DOM (Document Object Model). So `$('.search-form .field #city')` or `$('#city')` will both select the same element.

Comment: Show your HTML, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if($('.search-form #city').find('option').length==0 || $('.search-form #city').find(':selected').length==0)
 $('.search-form #city').hide();
```